# Intercept Ajax to obtain $_GET variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

Desperately in need of help! I wrote a php script to curl to this page

```
$loginUrl = 'http://agentnet.propertyguru.com.sg/ex_login?w=1&redirect=/ex_home';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
$cookie = realpath('cookie.txt');  // 'FSPrompt-6496=completed;' is stored in this file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5';
$request_headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);
$msg = curl_exec($ch);
```

However the page could detect that I was trying to php curl to it. I thought that it was due to a javascript cookie and hence I manually recreated the cookie and stored it in $cookie.

However it turned out that was not the issue. On further investigation, the cause is an ajax (I think) script that redirects to /distil_identify_cookie.html?uid=..., then back to the initial login page. I have no clue how to intercept this ajax redirection and obtain uid. The ajax code is as follows.

```
(function(e) {
  try {
    if (e.XMLHttpRequest && !e.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.dH) {
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.dH = "DVAH75442039325324";
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.dU = "/xhr.258242576821637.js?PID=3119DF0B-3C06-308A-88B4-6118E4B86D16";
      var t = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
      t.dOpen = t.open;
      t.open = function(e, t, n, r, i) {
        this.dOpen.apply(this, arguments);
        var s = new RegExp("^(((https?:)?//" + location.hostname + "([/]|$))|(/[^/]))");
        if (t.match(s) || !t.match(/^https?:\/\//) && t.match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]/)) {
          this.setRequestHeader.apply(this, ["X-Distil-Ajax", this.dH])
        }
      };
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = t.open;
      var n = setInterval(function() {
        var e = new XMLHttpRequest;
        e.open("GET", e.dU, true);
        e.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (e.readyState == 4 && e.status != 404) {
            var t = e.getResponseHeader("X-AH");
            var r = e.getResponseHeader("X-XU");
            if (t && r) {
              XMLHttpRequest.prototype.dU = r;
              XMLHttpRequest.prototype.dH = t
            }
          } else if (e.status == 404) {
            clearInterval(n)
          }
        };
        e.send()
      }, 27e4)
    }
  } catch (r) {}
})(window)
```

I got no clue from the headers. Please help!

Comment: I'm guessing they really don't want you to use anything other than a browser to log in ?

Comment: I suppose they don't. But I am their paying customer and want it integrated to my website. It's more productive than filling up multiple forms (^_^);

Comment: Judging by the given ajax code, it sets custom HTTP header "X-Distil-Ajax". So you have to reproduce it in your curl request.

Comment: How do I reproduce that in a curl request? When I curl to the login page, the page gets redirected straight away even with curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);.. can you kindly show me a code snippet illustrating this?